# Uwsgi: "Cannot assign requested address"

Tags: python, django, uwsgi, ports

So I have a django project all set and ready to go, and then I attempted to start it using uwsgi via this command

```
# uwsgi --http :5000 --module myProject.wsgi
```

This then returns this error log

```
** Starting uWSGI 2.0.3 (32bit) on [Sun Apr 13 14:23:55 2014] ***
compiled with version: 4.6.3 on 13 April 2014 14:06:52
os: Linux-2.6.32-042stab078.26 #1 SMP Wed Jun 19 11:05:34 MSK 2013
nodename: vps
machine: i686
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /root/HomeworkTasker
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 191584
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
bind(): Cannot assign requested address [core/socket.c line 759]
```

After some googling it seems it has been said that this address is already in use, I have determined this is not the case for multiple reasons. The first of these reasons is that if I go into a python shell, I can bind 0.0.0.0:5000 manually with python. The other reason is that if I go netstat, port 5000 is NOT listed. Anything I can do here or am I SOL?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution Found:

Make sure your interfaces are correct by running

```
ifconfig lo up
```